# *Ngfor in div class not working - Angular 6 and Bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ngfor, angular-bootstrap, angular-ng-if

I am implementing a REST service in Angular. Everything works fine. The film is a JSON object as you can see printed below of the picture. I cannot manage to print the results inside the boxes (ngif), but I can in the ngfor. Everything works fine as I said, except this:

```
<button (click)="getFilm(title.value); title.value=''">Buscar Pelicula</button>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="list-group">
        <p class="list-group-item" *ngIf='film'>Titulo: {{film.title}}</p>
        <p class="list-group-item" *ngIf='film'>Year: {{film.year}}</p>
        <p class="list-group-item" *ngIf='film'>Director:  {{film.director}}</p>
        <p class="list-group-item" *ngIf='film'>Reparto: {{film.reparto}}</p>
        <p class="list-group-item" *ngIf='film'>Urlvideo: {{film.urlvideo}}</p>
        <p class="list-group-item" *ngIf='film'>Urlvideo: {{film.urlimagen}}</p>

        <p *ngFor="let film of film">{{film.title}}, {{film.year}}, {{film.director}},
        {{film.reparto}},{{film.urlvideo}},<br>Imagen: <img src="{{film.urlimagen}}"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I won't upload *all* the code as it would be too verbose. I want to have this `ngFor` in the `div class` (so if I have two films, there will be two "tables".

I do not really know why; `*ngIf` is not working either.

[image]

I have tried putting `ngfor` in the `div class` (the second one), but it is not working in any way...

The JSON content in the case of "Interstellar" that I obtain in my REST service, is the next one: `[{"id":8,"title":"Interstellar","year":"2014","director":"Christopher Nolan","reparto":"Jessica Chastain, Matthew, Matt","urlvideo":"https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/UoSSbmD9vqc","urlimagen":"http://www.fotogramas.es/var/ezflow_site/storage/images/peliculas/interstellar/7193613-12-esl-ES/Interstellar.jpg"}]`

And that is how I get it (you cannot get it as I implement it in another project).

```
@Injectable()
export class servicioRest {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getFilm(title: string){
        let url = "http://localhost:8080/buscar/"+title;
        return this.http.get(url).pipe(map(response => response.json()));
    }
```

Comment: Please add a json for the film object.

Comment: The film object is a Json. I'll edit the question so it is more clear! @AnuradhaGunasekara

Comment: Can you change *ngFor="let film of film" to *ngFor="let filmItem of film" and use filmItem instead of film

Comment: But that won't change anything. The `ngIf`is not working. the `ngFor`is working fine. But I have tried to put it in the boxes (creating several boxes if there are several films with the same name, etc), and I can't manage how. @PadmapriyaVishnuvardhan

Comment: I think, you are checking object inside `*ngIf` thats why it doesn't work. `*ngIf` only contains true and false value not object.

Comment: You are facing the async issue here. can you add {{film}} before <p class="list-group-item" *ngIf='film'>Titulo: {{film.title}}</p> to ensure you had got the json properly.

Comment: As @PadmapriyaVishnuvardhan said, change the ngFor .Also bring the ngFor to an upper div (above `ngIf` )and then instead of printing `film.title` etc in the `ngIf`s, print `filmItem.name`

Comment: Does your JSON contain an array of films, or just a single object? (it would be helpful to have the JSON structure attached to the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log (`<p *ngFor="let film of film">...</p>`) suggests that `film` is an array of objects. As such, the following should work:

```
<div class="list-group" *ngFor="let filmItem of film">
    <p class="list-group-item" *ngIf="filmItem.title">Titulo: {{filmItem.title}}</p>
    <p class="list-group-item" *ngIf="filmItem.year">Year: {{filmItem.year}}</p>
    <p class="list-group-item" *ngIf="filmItem.director">Director:  {{filmItem.director}}</p>
    <p class="list-group-item" *ngIf="filmItem.reparto">Reparto: {{filmItem.reparto}}</p>
    <p class="list-group-item" *ngIf="filmItem.urlvideo">Urlvideo: {{filmItem.urlvideo}}</p>
    <p class="list-group-item" *ngIf="filmItem.urlimagen">Urlvideo: {{filmItem.urlimagen}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked as you said, but if there were 2 or more films with the same name, it bugged with `filmItem`. Only with `film`it works fine! Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with `same name`?  Normally, there shouldn't be an issue, as `filmItem` is only visible within the `*ngFor`.

Comment: This is implementing a rest service. So if I have, imagine, 2 "Interstellar" instead of 1, the `ngFor` works but instead of creating 2 "boxes", it creates 4, which shouldn't be. Without `filmItem`it works fine. Film is a Json that I get from the rest service. Maybe it would be clearer if I uploaded all the code, but it would be too verbous...

Comment: Uploading the complete JSON is not necessary, but having the basic structure would be helpful, yes ;)

Comment: I edited the question with the Json and the Rest Service! But the question is already solved thanks to all of you!